# PHP file is not writable error.

Tags: php

I have config.php, I did a ls-l on that file which shows -rwxrwxr-x   read, write and executable.

but on the PHP script,  is_writable(config.php)function shows the file is not writable.

why is that?

Comment: Who owns the file? And who runs php?

Comment: Is the user that PHP runs as in the same group as the owner of the file?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: technically `same group as the owner of the file` is not correct, as long as you can assign any group as the file owner

Comment: I own the file, and I run the php , all under admin account

Comment: @lilzz: how exactly do you run it?

Comment: Are you definitely checking the right location? Have you tried file_exists() ?

Comment: http://localhost/index.php which try to write config.php. I runs it on a browser. The file exists and I verify that.

Comment: OK, I solve it by chmod 777 folder and then chmod 777 config.php inside.   now its OK.    instead of -rwxrwxr-x now it becomes -rwxrwxrwx

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the php script runs as a different user than you running ls -l
Try executing: chmod +w config.php

Answer (score 0):

which group does the file belong to?

the rwxrwxr-x says, that the file is writable by the user and the group, but not by others.

now if your webserver process (that hosts php), is accessing the file, it is doing so as user 'nobody' or 'www-data', so THAT is the user that needs to own the file or have group-write-access to it.

a quick fix: if you do a chown of the file to the user under which apache is running, you should be fine.

Comment: the file belongs to admin which is me. and I run the php script. but how do I verify I running apache as myself, the admin?

Comment: @lilzz in php, do echo shell_exec('whoami');

Comment: well both apache and the ls-l of the config.php show my name as the user.

Comment: then i am speechless... maybe post output of: whoami; ls -l config.php; php -v; php --ini; php -f config.php